# How to add a shadow to a kCAFillRuleEvenOdd mask layer

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, cashapelayer

I have a custom view for tutorials.
the hall screen is black and there is a "hole" in the show cased view.
I want to add a shadow around the "hole"

i tried this:

```
backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
alpha = 0.5

// Create the shape to mask
let path = createPathOfShape(shape)

//this masking works - adding the "hole"
let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
maskLayer.frame = bounds
maskLayer.fillColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
maskLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd
maskLayer.path = path.CGPath
layer.mask = maskLayer

//this is not working - adding the shadow to the "hole"
let glow = CAShapeLayer()
glow.frame = bounds
glow.fillColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
glow.path = path.CGPath
glow.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
glow.shadowRadius = 10
glow.shadowOffset = CGSizeZero
glow.shadowOpacity = 0.5
layer.addSublayer(glow)
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks